# How to delete the products not up-to-date using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to the structure in the example below.
The problem that the product code is combination of groups and categories, however the third part of code is my reference , I need to delete all old versions of the products and keep the most up to date. I am stuck in the logic, please any hint or help?

```
CREATE TABLE Productsss (id varchar(20), date_inserted datetime , pname varchar(200))
INSERT INTO Productsss VALUES
('HDGD-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-10' ,'ANYNAME'), -- To be deleted
('WEEE-DHGHD-70001-DDHHH', '2010-10-10' ,'ANYNAME'), 
('23DD-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-13' ,'ANYNAME'), -- To be deleted
('EEEE-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-14' ,'ANYNAME'), 
('3323-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-15' ,'ANYNAME')
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is about.  Your sample data has nothing called "code" or "product code" in the table.  It has no explanation of the versions and what they mean.  Please elaborate.  And based on your rules, it is curious that the most recent row in the table is deleted.

Comment: I mean the id field

Comment: I need to delete the old ones, this is a manufacturing data so the code is generated automatically but the third part of code(Id) is the real code

Comment: So the old versions of the id are useless

Comment: @Gordon Linoff the goal is cleansing

Comment: The version is the insertion date, the third Column

Comment: Example the second record and the fifth to be not deleted because the are the recent versions of 70001 and 90001 while the others need to be deleted. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get the rows that needs to be deleted.
This is assuming that your id field always have the same length

With sample data:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT id = 'HDGD-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', date_inserted = '2010-10-10' , pname = 'ANYNAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'WEEE-DHGHD-70001-DDHHH', '2010-10-10' ,'ANYNAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT '23DD-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-13' ,'ANYNAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EEEE-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-14' ,'ANYNAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3323-DHGHD-90001-DDHHH', '2010-10-15' ,'ANYNAME'
),
CTE2 AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(id,12,5) ORDER BY DATE_INSERTED DESC) AS
        RN, *
FROM CTE)



DELETE FROM Productsss 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CTE2
WHERE RN > 1)
```

Final query

```
WITH CTE2 AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(id,12,5) ORDER BY DATE_INSERTED DESC) AS
        RN, *
FROM Productsss)

DELETE FROM Productsss 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CTE2
WHERE RN > 1)
```

Comment: I am sorry but it is not easy to hardcode thousands of id list

Comment: With the third part and the length you are right

Comment: The query is dealing with table, query should include data

Comment: @Learner1111  Edited the answer with the final query....

Comment: Thanks you, appreciated